# Scalaで整数型のリストの総和を再帰で求める方法について

Tags: scala

Scalaで総数を返す再帰のコードでよく使われるのが、下記のような書き方です。

```scala
 def sumList(list:List[Int]): Int = {
    list match {
        case Nil => 0
        case x::list => x + sumList(list)
    }        
}
```

case Nilがマッチする為には引数のlistをtailするしかないことは理解出来ました。

が、 case x::list => x + sumList(list)を実行することでlistがtailされていくことがわかりません... ::演算子は左側の要素を右側のリストに連結するものなので、混乱しています。

なぜこの再帰呼び出しで引数のlistがtailされていくのでしょうか？

Comment: 同じ変数名listがあるから混乱しますね。`case head::tail => head + sumList(tail)`　こう書けば解りやすいかな？パターンマッチをしていて、listがからでない限りheadとtailに分割することができるのでマッチします。

Comment: ありがとうございます！バッチリわかりました！！！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

変数名を整理し、途中経過をprintしてみました。

```
def sumList(list:List[Int]): Int = {
    list match {
        case Nil => 0
        case head::tail => {
            println(head)
            println(tail)
            head + sumList(tail)
        }
    }        
}
```

結果は次のとおり。

```
scala> sumList(List(1,2,3,4,5))
1
List(2, 3, 4, 5)
2
List(3, 4, 5)
3
List(4, 5)
4
List(5)
5
List()
res10: Int = 15
```

`::`はおっしゃるように左側の要素を右側のリストに連結するので`1 :: List(2,3,4,5)`は`List(1,2,3,4,5)`と同じです。

ここでは逆に`match`しようとしているので`List(1,2,3,4,5)`が`head::tail`、つまり`1::List(2,3,4,5)`にマッチしてheadが1, tailが(2,3,4,5)になります。あとは再帰しています。単純に先頭から１要素取り出すと思っていいでしょう。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。リストをheadとtailに展開していることが理解できていませんでしたが、ご教示頂いてバッチリ理解出来ました。

ListをConsクラスの(head:A,tail:List[A])にパターンマッチして、tailを抜き出して再帰で回していることがやっと理解出来ました。

ありがとうございました！